# Is the given topological space Hausdorff?

Tags: general-topology

Let $A$ be the set obtained by removing the set $$Y:=\{(0, y)\ |\ y\neq 0\}$$ from $\mathbb{R}^2$. Clearly, the set $Y$ is the $y$-axis minus the origin. Let $$\tau_2:\ \text{quotient topology on A due to the following surjective map}\ \Phi ,$$ where
$$\Phi:\mathbb{R}^2\to A$$ defined by $$\Phi(x, y)= (x, y)\ \text{for}\ x\neq 0, \ \text{and}\ \Phi(0, y)= (0, 0)\ \text{for all}\ y.$$
Let $\tau_2$ be the resulting quotient topology on $A$, i.e., $\tau_2$ is the smallest topology for which $\Phi$ is continuous.

I want to know whether $(A, \tau_2)$ is Hausdorff?

My thought: I assume it is Hausdorff. I took two points $(0, 0)$ and $(\epsilon, 0)$ in $S$ for some $\epsilon >0$. This means that there are two disjoint open sets $U$ and $V$ such that $$(0, 0)\in U, \ (\epsilon, 0)\in V, \ U\cap V=\emptyset.$$Since $U$ is open, we must have $$\Phi^{-1}(U)=U\cup ((-\delta, \delta)\times \mathbb{R}),\ \ \Phi^{-1}(V)=V$$ for some $\delta>0$ by definition of quotient topology. Have I reached to some contradiction or thinking it in the right manner?

Comment: I don't think there's any contradiction for these two points.  For example, $[(-\epsilon, 0) \times \mathbb{R}] \cup \{ (0, 0) \} \cup [(0, \epsilon/2) \times \mathbb{R}]$ and $(\epsilon/2, 3\epsilon/2) \times \mathbb{R}$ are disjoint open subsets of $A$ which are both open (the first is open because its inverse image in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is $(-\epsilon, \epsilon/2) \times \mathbb{R}$); and they separate $(0, 0)$ and $(\epsilon, 0)$.

Comment: Away from $(0,0)$ things behave like they do in $\mathbb{R}^2$ so focus on $(0,0) \in A$. I believe that all open sets about $(0,0) \in A$ take the form $\Phi\big(\{(-\delta,\delta) \times \mathbb{R}\}\big)$, otherwise when you take a preimage you get a "spike" on the y-axis, which of course isn't open (you appear to have realised this would be an issue). So given $(0,0) \in A$ and some other $(a,b) \neq (0,0) \in A$, how can you pick $\delta$ (which should depend on $a$) and some $\epsilon  >0 $ so that $\Phi\big(\{(-\delta,\delta) \times \mathbb{R}\}\big)  \cap B_{\epsilon}((a,b)) = \{\}$

Comment: Your statement about $\Phi^{-1}(U)$ is not correct. But even if it where, you could choose $\delta$ small relative to $\epsilon$ and avoid the contradiction, no? So maybe you should think about trying to prove that $(A,\tau_2)$ is Hausdorff.

Comment: @Dylan I don't think all open neighborhoods of $(0,0)$ are necessarily of that form, nor do the neighborhoods of that form even comprise a neighborhood basis.  For example, consider $A \cap \{ (x, y) \mid |xy| < 1 \}$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Ohhh clever, weirdly I felt something was off, hence why I opted to leave in "I believe" despite being low on character count - I'll keep this example in mind for sure. To OP - the open sets I mentioned will still enable you to prove Hausdorff, but it doesn't describe all such open sets.